# Woo Commerce - Offer to register at checkout (don't force)

Tags: woocommerce, registration

As the title says, is there anyway I can allow a customer to register at checkout. The ideal situation would be to get their shipping and billing address included in the registration at the same time they enter it for the actual purchase. 
However, I don't want to force the customer to register if they don't really want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of woocommerce you have, but certainly the latest vesion let's you set if customer's can create an account at checkout, or if they can check out without account (guest checkout).

These settings are all in: woocommerce/settings/accounts & privacy tab